# How do I configure the new OAuth functionality in Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, adfs, windows-server-2012

I am trying to test an existing OAuth client using the OAuth AS now available in Windows Server 2012 R2.  Microsoft has been very vocal in advertising its availability in many venues now over the past month or two.  The trouble is that the documentation is severely lagging the implementation.  I can't find any documentation telling me how to configure the AS or even what the authorization endpoint URL is or the token endpoint URL (they claim to support to code grant flow of OAuth 2.0).